# Search for email addresses in visual studio search box using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The regular expression search in visual studio is very limited, I need a regular expression to search for email addresses in a very big solution.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains the problem

> You can use a **specific set** of regular expressions in the Find what and
>   Replace with fields of the Find and Replace Window

*** EDIT ***
I need something work with VS 2010 SP1 but not VS 2012

Comment: I would use a 3rd party editor like Notepad++ if you need a real regex tool.

Comment: Please specify the limitations you are trying to overcome.

Comment: Try any online available ready email regular expressions, it won't work on the search box of visual studio, because it doesn't accept any regular expression, but a strange subset of regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

open visual studio find dialog and Try This Option:I already done this.

Email Regex:`\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`

You can specify your limitation.

[image]

Comment: I already try this in vs 2012 with no problem,what,s Syntax error?